# Determine if following sibling contains node with same value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm sure this should be very simple - but I'm having trouble with context!

Example XML:

```xml
<test>
<HtlSeg>
    <SegNum>1</SegNum>
    <StartDt>20130624</StartDt>
    <NumNights>2</NumNights>
    <Conf>28618</Conf>
</HtlSeg>
<CommentInfo>
    <CommentNum>1</CommentNum>
    <SegMatch>28618</SegMatch>
    <Comment>THIS IS A TEST</Comment>
</CommentInfo>
<CommentInfo>
    <CommentNum>2</CommentNum>
    <SegMatch>28618</SegMatch>
    <Comment>HOTEL BOOKED</Comment>
</CommentInfo>
<CommentInfo>
    <CommentNum>3</CommentNum>
    <SegMatch>28618</SegMatch>
    <Comment>NON REFUNDABLE</Comment>
</CommentInfo>
<CommentInfo>
    <CommentNum>4</CommentNum>
    <SegMatch>1459</SegMatch>
    <Comment>CAR BOOKING</Comment>
</CommentInfo>
<CommentInfo>
    <CommentNum>5</CommentNum>
    <SegMatch>1528</SegMatch>
    <Comment>AIR BOOKING</Comment>
</CommentInfo>
<CommentInfo>
    <CommentNum>6</CommentNum>
    <SegMatch>1528</SegMatch>
    <Comment>NON REFUNDABLE</Comment>
</CommentInfo>
<CommentInfo>
    <CommentNum>7</CommentNum>
    <SegMatch>1528</SegMatch>
    <Comment>NON SMOKING</Comment>
</CommentInfo>
```

In an XSLT my context node is the `<HtlSeg>`.

I am tryin to access the `<CommentInfo>` nodes where the `<SegMatch>` node equals the `<Conf>` node of the `<HotelSeg>`.

The xpath I've tried is `following-sibling::CommentInfo[SegMatch=Conf]/Comment`

However doesn't return anything. I think I've lost context from the `<HotelSeg>` when using the `Conf' in the xpath - but Im sure this must be possible in a simple Xpath without having to declare variables??

Cheers
Darren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`current()` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#misc-func)

```
[SegMatch=current()/Conf]
```

Comment: Ah OK thanks!  current() is an XSLT only function - I was testing my xpaths using XMLSpy and the xpath tester - which doesn't allow you to use the xslt functions!  Many thanks for the help!